# Display not supported by outlook-2010

Tags: html, css, outlook, outlook-2010

I want to do some styling for a page that gets opened in ms-outlook 2010.
Problem is that it doesn't support the `display` attribute.
Does anyone know a good alternative for it?

A possible solution would be to create a class that has properties similar to `display: block`.
Would this work? How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are we talking about building an HTML email here? If so then for maximum compatibility we should be coding like 1999 and using tables with inline CSS.

A guide to what CSS is supported in various email clients can be found over at [Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) and they also have a range of [free templates](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/templates/) you can download, use or just learn from. Zurb [also have some templates](http://zurb.com/ink/templates.php) you can download and play with.